# How to look for a specific file in first level directories in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, os.walk

I have a semi-complicated directory traversal that I need to perform.  I have a program that I wrote that will require a SOURCE directory as a required parameter.  I then need to get a list of FIRST LEVEL directories as I really only care about the first level.  I then need to take that list of FIRST LEVEL directories and look to see if it contains a specific file.  If it does, I want to add that first level directory to a list.  So for I have done the following to get a list of the first level source.  I am just unsure on how I would look under each of these directories to find the existence of a file. (something like *.proj).  Any help you could provide would be awesome to point me in the right direction!

```
 for name in os.listdir(args.source):
        if os.path.isdir(args.source):
            self.tempSource.append(os.path.join(args.source, name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) to search for files:

```
import glob
import os
files = []
for name in os.listdir(args.source):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        files.append(glob.glob(os.path.join(args.source, name + "/*.proj"))) # match any files ending with .proj
```

The `*.proj` uses a wildcard, it will match any file ending with the extension `.proj`
There is another short tutorial [here](http://pymotw.com/2/glob/):

Comment: So I am getting the list of first level directories under the initial source, but if a .proj file exists under one of the first level directories I would like to add it to a list.  Not seeing how the above code would accomplish that?  I don't know the exact file name of the .proj file, so I would need to support a wild card of some sort.  The extension will always be .proj though.

Comment: just append the result to a list, the `/*.proj` is a wildcard

Comment: Perfect.  That is what I needed.  Also, thanks for the short tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking whether the source directory is a directory repeatedly. You need to check the items inside that directory to see if they are directories. You also need to join the paths because `listdir` only returns names.

```
subpaths = (os.path.join(args.source, name) for name in os.listdir(args.source))
subdirs = list(filter(os.path.isdir, subpaths))
```